# Django startup code with wsgi lazy loading

Tags: django, apache, wsgi

I am running a Django application using Apache+mod_wsgi. When starting up Apache, it seems that the wsgi always lazyloads its app which means that no code is executed when Apache is started.
Only when the first request comes in is the whole app loaded, initalized, etc and returned to the user.

As I need to run some code without having to rely on the first request, I was wondering if this "lazy loading" can somehow be turned off or workedaround?

I tried the WSGIImportScript VirtualHost directive and the "WSGILazyInitialization Off" server one but without luck, the app still loads lazily on first request.

Any idea?

EDIT:
To update with the exact config:

- running on Ubuntu 13.10

  - apache2 2.4.6-2ubuntu2.1
  - libapache2-mod-wsgi, 3.4-4
- startup.py
- I put 'WSGILazyInitialization Off' in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/wsgi.conf and /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
- I have the following in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:

  WSGIDaemonProcess lh.test.com processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}
  WSGIProcessGroup lh.test.com
  WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/myapp/src/wsgi.py
  WSGIImportScript /home/user/myapp/src/startup.py process-group='%{GLOBAL}' application-group='%{GLOBAL}'
- and startup.py contains:

  import wsgi
  print 'zzzzz'

Nothing appears in the logs...

Comment: What script did you import with the `WSGIImportScript` directive? Did you put debug logging into the script to verify it was not executed?

Comment: WSGILazyInitialization has got nothing to do with what you want to do. Amend your question with the actual Apache configuration showing WSGIScriptAlias, WSGIDaemonProcess, WSGIProcessGroup and WSGIImportScript directives you are using. Also mention what mod_wsgi version you are using. Newer mod_wsgi versions have an easier way than using WSGIImportScript.

Comment: I updated my description above if you guys could take a look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Gram's Answer to this question [when-does-apache2-execute-a-wsgi-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746269/when-does-apache2-execute-a-wsgi-script-when-using-daemon-process-groups/16747089#16747089) he points out the new mod_wsgi > 3 handling of this. Which is (in a nutshell) add the 'process-group' and 'application-group' to your WSGIScriptAlias

See the Features Added section in [ChangesInVersion0300](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ChangesInVersion0300)

--- sniped from documentation ---

For WSGIScriptAlias (but not WSGIScriptAliasMatch) where both 'process-group' and 'application-group' parameters are provided, and neither use expansion variables that can only be evaluated at the time of request handling, this will also cause the WSGI script file to be preloaded when the process starts, rather than being lazily loaded only when first request for application arrives.

--- end sniped from documentation ---

**Try this: ( it worked for me )**

Try making your apache configuration directives look like this:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/myapp/src/wsgi.py \
                  application-group='%{GLOBAL}' process-group='lh.test.com' 

WSGIDaemonProcess lh.test.com processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}
WSGIProcessGroup lh.test.com 
# Probably wont need this anymore.
#WSGIImportScript /home/user/myapp/src/startup.py \
#                  process-group='%{GLOBAL}' application-group='%{GLOBAL}'
```

Now put your `print "zzzzz"` at the bottom of your /home/user/myapp/src/wsgi.py file.

**Finally:** If this does not work for you, please modify your question so your configuration is in code-blocks to make it more readable. Also include where these are in the apache configuration directives. i.e. if they are in VirtualHost sections etc. As there are some rules related to where and what order these directives appear, and people wont be able to see the problem if you dont include it.

Cheers

Comment: it works, thanks Jeff! What I find weird is that now when I start Apache, i get two yyy lines in my error.log. I thought it may be somehow related to the processes=2 parameter of WSGIDaemonProcess but changing that value to 1 or 3 still produced 2 lines of yyy. Any idea?

Comment: What is more, on apache shutdown, one of the two processes refuses to terminate nicely:
[Mon Jan 06 16:06:09.559501 2014] [core:warn] [pid 11437:tid 140451214522240] AH00045: child process 11441 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Mon Jan 06 16:06:11.560812 2014] [core:warn] [pid 11437:tid 140451214522240] AH00045: child process 11441 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Mon Jan 06 16:06:13.563002 2014] [core:error] [pid 11437:tid 140451214522240] AH00046: child process 11441 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL

Comment: @Rok did you ever figure out your two yyy lines? ( I don't have any idea on that )

Comment: Hi @Jeff, yes I did resolve it, thanks to Graham, see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20958553/wsgi-startup-why-two-identical-processes. Definitely a step up in my wsgi knowledge :)

Comment: @Rok awesome, glad you solved it. I modified my response to properly define the process-group. Note I believe it worked for me because I also defined the WSGIProcessGroup explicitly. Just the same tho, I changed the WSGIScriptAlias line to match what Gram suggested.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff, great that you updated it to keep the full solution in one place, it may benefit someone else as well...Cheers

Comment: @Jeff I tried the solution have above (swapping out paths and such), but I got a `Syntax error on line 13 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/MYSITE:
WSGI process group not yet configured.` error. I tried moving the lines around, but it didn't help. Are there any restrictions on the  naming here, or is there anything else obvious you can think of that would cause this problem?

Comment: @SticLoofah, do you have a apache `<Directory home/user/myapp/src/>` directive configured for your wsgi application? See Graham's [QuickConfigurationGuide](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide) about Delegation To Daemon Process for more information on groups.

Comment: @SticLoofah, I just went and read the wsgi source and it looks like this error can be raised in one of 4 situations. Tell me every configuration option you have with `WSGI` in front of it please.