# Run startup code when mod_wsgi autoreload after file changes

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I have mod_wsgi, daemon mode, and Django.

I could make mod_wsgi run code at startup if I provide `application-group` and `process-group` params to WSGIScriptAlias - https://stackoverflow.com/a/20930912/203485 (instead by default it'll run it on first request).

But how could I make it run same startup code after it reloads workers automatically after wsgi file changes (you just upload new files and `touch` wsgi file)? It then won't run startup code until first request.

I need to do heavy initialization just after workers start and preferably without server reload (it requires root).

Answer (score 0):

You can probably just call a function at module scope of your WSGI script.